# Custom ssh properties with sshd socket

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, configuration

I recently changed to Ubuntu Sever 23 from Ubuntu Server 20 and want to adapt my SSH configuration on the new system the same way it was on the old system.

I had several custom properties in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, e.g.

```
Port 22

PermitRootLogin no

PasswordAuthentication no
Match Address 192.168.1.*
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Now as far as I understood Ubuntu 23 uses SSH sockets instead of a service which means I have to add files to `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/`.

For the port to which the system listens this works quite fine but I couldn't find any info online about how to restrict access for root or disable the password access for users outside my local network. Does anyone know the syntax here or is this not possible through sockets?

Answer (score 2):

> Now as far as I understood Ubuntu 23 uses SSH sockets instead of a service which means I have to add files to /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/.

You are conflating two largely unrelated things.

Ubuntu 23 uses socket activation for ssh; that means that rather than running sshd all the time, sshd is only started when someone tries to connect. Because systemd is listening rather than sshd, you need to modify the `ssh.socket` configuration to change the listening port. It doesn't look like you're trying to do that, so you don't need to change the way you're things.

The use of socket activation has **no impact** on where the sshd configuration files are stored; as always, these are still located in `/etc/ssh`.

Just like in earlier versions, you can modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` directly, or you can drop fragments into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d`.